# What would be the equivalent of keras.layers.Masking in pytorch?

Tags: keras, deep-learning, pytorch

I have time-series sequences which I needed to keep the length of sequences fixed to a number by padding zeroes into matrix and using keras.layers.Masking in keras I could neglect those padded zeros for further computations, I am wondering how could it be done in Pytorch?

Either I need to do the padding in pytroch and pytorch can't handle the sequences with varying lengths what is the equivalent to Masking layer of keras in pytorch, or if pytorch handles the sequences with varying lengths, how could it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [PackedSequence](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/nn.html#packedsequence) class as equivalent to keras masking. you can find more features at `torch.nn.utils.rnn`

Here putting example from [packing for variable-length sequence inputs for rnn](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/simple-working-example-how-to-use-packing-for-variable-length-sequence-inputs-for-rnn/2120)

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.autograd import Variable

batch_size = 3
max_length = 3
hidden_size = 2
n_layers =1

# container
batch_in = torch.zeros((batch_size, 1, max_length))

#data
vec_1 = torch.FloatTensor([[1, 2, 3]])
vec_2 = torch.FloatTensor([[1, 2, 0]])
vec_3 = torch.FloatTensor([[1, 0, 0]])

batch_in[0] = vec_1
batch_in[1] = vec_2
batch_in[2] = vec_3

batch_in = Variable(batch_in)

seq_lengths = [3,2,1] # list of integers holding information about the batch size at each sequence step

# pack it
pack = torch.nn.utils.rnn.pack_padded_sequence(batch_in, seq_lengths, batch_first=True)

>>> pack
PackedSequence(data=Variable containing:
 1  2  3
 1  2  0
 1  0  0
[torch.FloatTensor of size 3x3]
, batch_sizes=[3])


# initialize
rnn = nn.RNN(max_length, hidden_size, n_layers, batch_first=True) 
h0 = Variable(torch.randn(n_layers, batch_size, hidden_size))

#forward 
out, _ = rnn(pack, h0)

# unpack
unpacked, unpacked_len = torch.nn.utils.rnn.pad_packed_sequence(out)

>>> unpacked
Variable containing:
(0 ,.,.) = 
 -0.7883 -0.7972
  0.3367 -0.6102
  0.1502 -0.4654
[torch.FloatTensor of size 1x3x2]
```

more you would find this article useful. [Jum to Title - "How the PackedSequence object works"] - [link](https://medium.com/huggingface/understanding-emotions-from-keras-to-pytorch-3ccb61d5a983)

Comment: This code snippet contains a bug. The input to RNN should be (batch_size, seq_length, feature_dim) when batch_size is given first. In the given link they have updated the example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a packed sequence to mask a timestep in the sequence dimension:

```
batch_mask = ...  # boolean mask e.g. (seq x batch)
# move `padding` at right place then it will be cut when packing
compact_seq = torch.zeros_like(x)
for i, seq_len in enumerate(batch_mask.sum(0)):
    compact_seq[:seq_len, i] = x[batch_mask[:,i],i]
# pack in sequence dimension (the number of agents)
packed_x = pack_padded_sequence(compact_seq, batch_mask.sum(0).cpu().numpy(), enforce_sorted=False)
packed_scores, rnn_hxs = nn.GRU(packed_x, rnn_hxs)
# restore sequence dimension
scores, _ = pad_packed_sequence(packed_scores)
# restore order, moving padding in its place    
scores = torch.zeros((*batch_mask.shape,scores.size(-1))).to(scores.device).masked_scatter(batch_mask.unsqueeze(-1), scores)
```

instead use a mask select/scatter to mask in the batch dimension:

```
batch_mask = torch.any(x, -1).unsqueeze(-1)  # boolean mask (batch,1)
batch_x = torch.masked_select(x, batch_mask).reshape(-1, x.size(-1))
batch_rnn_hxs = torch.masked_select(rnn_hxs, batch_mask).reshape(-1, rnn_hxs.size(-1))
batch_rnn_hxs = nn.GRUCell(batch_x, batch_rnn_hxs)
rnn_hxs = rnn_hxs.masked_scatter(batch_mask, batch_rnn_hxs)  # restore batch
```

Note that using scatter function is safe for gradient backpropagation