# Is there an alterntive to tf.keras.layers.Masking in PyTorch? Or Is there any way to implement it from scratch?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, pytorch

I have a time series dataset with a lot of NAs that I need to use with LSTM network. Previously with TensorFlow, I used to initially replace NAs with -1(Which is not present in the data) and use  `tf.keras.layers.Masking`([Documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Masking)) within the model to stop learning when the model encounters -1 and resume when encountering something else. Since then, I have switched to PyTorch and need to use something similar again. So, my question is this: Is there an alternative to this in PyTorch? Or is there any way to do this while using PyTorch? See the code version of what I do below:

```
...
dataset.fillna(-1, inplace = True) # Replace na cells with -1 for masking in LSTM
...
...
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Masking(mask_value=-1,input_shape=(timesteps, features)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32))
...
...
```

Suggestion made below is different as in `tf.keras.layers.Masking`, for each timestep in the input tensor, if all values in the input tensor at that timestep are equal to `mask_value`(-1), then the timestep will be masked (skipped) in all downstream layers (as long as they support masking).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What would be the equivalent of keras.layers.Masking in pytorch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59545229/what-would-be-the-equivalent-of-keras-layers-masking-in-pytorch)

Comment: Hi @SzymonMaszke, thank you for the reply. In the example provided in the link, how would the zeros be interpreted by the RNN? In TensorFlow, `tf.keras.layers.Masking` masks a sequence by using a mask value to skip time-steps. Whenever mask value is encountered, learning is stopped and resumes with normal data.

Comment: You can use PackedSequence and simply provide data of different length (via Python’s lists) to it. Instead of masking simply delete time-steps which won’t be used for teaching RNN.